# MVC4: url routing with email as parameter

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-mvc-routing

I have this url which works absolutely fine on my VS web server

```
http://localhost:4454/cms/account/edituser/email@domain.com (works)
```

but when I publish this site to IIS7.5 , it simply throws 404.

```
http://dev.test.com/cms/account/edituser/email@domian.com  (does not work)
```

but the strange things happens if I remove email address

```
http://dev.test.com/cms/account/edituser/email (works , no 404)
```

but if I change my url with query string it works fine

```
http://dev.test.com/cms/account/edituser?id=email@domain.com (works)
```

here is my route entry

```
routes.MapRoute(
             "Default", // Route name
             "{controller}/{action}/{id}", // URL with parameters
             new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }, // Parameter defaults
             new[] { "App.NameSpace.Web.Controllers" }
         );
```

weird thing I have noticed is that when server throws 404 error page , it is a standards iis 404 page not the one custom one I have. 
 so I was wondering is there any issue with my route mapping 
or IIS does not like the url which has email as parameter. but everything works fine with my local dev. 

Thanks

Answer (score 10):

Try url encoding the email address in the URL.

**EDIT**

UrlEncode + Base64?

```
    public static string ToBase64(this string value)
    {
        byte[] bytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(value);
        return Convert.ToBase64String(bytes);
    }

    public static string FromBase64(this string value)
    {
        byte[] bytes = Convert.FromBase64String(value);
        return Encoding.UTF8.GetString(bytes);
    }
```

In your view:

```
<a href="@Url.Action("MyAction", new { Id = email.ToBase64() })">Link</a>
```

In your controller

```
function ActionResult MyAction(string id){
   id = id.FromBase64();
   //rest of your logic here
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Raciel. MVC does encoding by itself like email%40domian.com

Comment: Where to add ToBase64 and FromBase64 functions?

Comment: @BasharAbuShamaa they are [extension methods](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383977.aspx). You need to add them to a public static class. Check the link provided for more info on extensions methods.

Answer (score 4):

`email@domain.com` contains characters which are not a legal part of the path (for good reason, they are often reserved for special functions). You'll need to quote/url encode these characters or pass them in the querystring.

Scott Hanselman has a [great post](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/ExperimentsInWackinessAllowingPercentsAnglebracketsAndOtherNaughtyThingsInTheASPNETIISRequestURL.aspx) on allowing "Naughty Things" in urls.