# Url with email address in ASP.NET MVC4

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-mvc-routing

I have a situation where I'm using URLs that could possibly contain email addresses. For example:

`http://MyUrl.com/Edit/Mike`

or

`http://MyUrl.com/Edit/bob@whatever.com`

According to [this StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15978555/mvc4-url-routing-with-email-as-parameter) it appears the easy way to get around this is to use a querystring instead. Is there a way I could set this up in the routing rule, where it would determine if value is invalid and have it fall back to a querystring?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about this:

Route:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "UserEdit",
    url: "Edit/{user}",
    defaults: new { controller = "User", action = "Edit" },
    constraints: new { user = @"[a-z0-9]+" /*Add valid characters here*/ }
);

routes.MapRoute(
    name: "UserEditWithIllegalChars",
    url: "Edit/",
    defaults: new { controller = "User", action = "Edit" }
);
```

The route will only match URLs like /Edit/Mike and Edit/?user=bob@whatever.com.

Generating the URL also works. For example

```
@Html.ActionLink("1", "Edit", "User", new { user = "Mike" }, new { })
@Html.ActionLink("2", "Edit", "User", new { user = "bob@whatever.com" }, new { })
```

Produces the same URLs as above

Controller:

```
public ActionResult Edit(string user)
```

Note:
1) you need to check if user is null
2) add valid characters into the constraint because I don't know all of them.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know about constraints.